# What is the difference between scale(mydata) and scale(mydata[-1])

Tags: r, scale

I want do clustering on my data set 'mydata'. Before doing clustering I have tried to scale my data set, for that I have used

```
mydatascaled <- scale(mydata)
```

and

```
mydatascaled <- scale(mydata[-1])
```

both given different output. What is the difference between these two

Answer (score 0):

`mydata[-1]` does not select the first column for scaling:

```
> mydata<- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3,3))
> mydata
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
> mydata[-1]
  V2 V3
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```